# Is it possible to let only a user selection trigger a SelectionChanged event on a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, selection, selectionchanged

SelectionChanged methods are triggered when the selection is changed by program. So, for example, calling `dataGridView.ClearSelection()` or `dataGridView.Rows[0].Selected = true` would call the method

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Is it possible to execute code *only when the user* changed the selection, e.g. by selecting a row/cell with the mouse or keyboard?

Comment: There's no good way to do it, refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650784/determine-if-changed-event-occurred-from-user-input-or-not

Comment: As far as i know: no. But you can add some logic to this method and write your code in it after if statement. I think you should be able to get some information about the event. Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to code this in

```
private bool _programmaticChange;

private void SomeMethod()
{
    _programmaticChange = true;
    dataGridView.ClearSelection();
    _programmaticChange = false;
}


private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_programmaticChange) return;
    // some code
}
```

this will make it run only on user actions